# Method of organising and deploying releases of a subsystem of related components using yum

Tags: deployment, centos, rpm, yum, rhel

We have a distributed subsystem consisting of multiple components, each component is deployed in it's own RPM package onto various different RHEL/CentOS environments.  For example the components might be called:

- JL_batman,
- JL_superman, and
- JL_wonderwoman.

And they are deployed as follows:

- host1:

  - JL_batman
  - JL_wonderwoman
- host2:

  - JL_superman

We do periodic system releases and also maintenance releases. So the initial few System Releases might look like this:

- SR1:

  - JL_batman-1.0-hg123.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.7-hg651.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm
- SR2:

  - JL_batman-2.0-hg137.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.7-hg651.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm
- SR3:

  - JL_batman-2.0-hg137.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.8-hg655.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm

So in each System Release not all packages are updated.  Currently we use symbolic links on the YUM repo for the packages that are not updated between releases:

- SR1:

  - JL_batman-1.0-hg123.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.7-hg651.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm
- SR2:

  - JL_batman-2.0-hg137.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.7-hg651.rpm --> ../SR1/superman-2.7-hg651.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm --> ..SR1/wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm
- SR3:

  - JL_batman-2.0-hg137.rpm --> ../SR2/batman-2.0-hg137.rpm
  - JL_superman-2.8-hg655.rpm
  - JL_wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm --> ..SR1/wonderwoman-1.1-hg101.rpm

Each release directory (SR1, SR2, SR3, ...) is a YUM repository.  We also use symlinks to link to the following rolling repositories:

- JL-old-stable --> SR1
- JL-stable --> SR2
- JL-testing --> SR3

This is all managed on the YUM repo server using some home grown scripts to pull packages from Jenkins and put them into the JL-testing repo (replacing any old versions there).  When SR3 testing is complete and it is promoted to stable, we jiggle the symlinks as follows:

- JL-old-stable --> SR2
- JL-stable --> SR3
- JL-testing --> SR4

Each production environment has the yum .repo file installed for JL-old-stable.repo and JL-stable.repo.  Test environments also have a JL-testing.repo file.  Then `yum upgrade 'JL_*'` is used on each environment to keep it up to date.  Works OK but has some issues, mainly:

1. When SR3 is promoted to stable, but we need to rollback to SR2 we need to use something like `yum --disablerepo='JL-*' --enablerepo='JL-old-stable' downgrade 'JL-*'`.
2. There is no way to easily rollback from SR3 (stable) to SR1 apart from installing a new JL-SR1.repo file and then using `yum --disablerepo='JL-*' --enablerepo='JL-SR1' downgrade 'JL-*'`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use a single RPM that provides no files, but `Requires` the various other packages *with exact versioning*. The "Version" of each of the config RPMs is just the release number.

`OurConfig_SR_1.noarch` requires:

- JL_batman = 1.0
- JL_superman = 2.7
- JL_wonderwoman = 1.1

`OurConfig_SR_2.noarch` requires:

- JL_batman = 2.0
- JL_superman = 2.7
- JL_wonderwoman = 1.1

Then you can have them all in a single repo and [versionlock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-versionlock.1.html) the `OurConfig` on the machine until you're ready to move it. A quick check with `rpm -qi OurConfig` can tell you what that system expects. Requiring the exact versions should stop an SR1 system from automatically upgrading `JL_batman` to 2.0 (I didn't test this of course!).

Comment: Thanks @aaron-d-marasco. I like that idea.  The only issue I can see is we need to deploy those components onto two different machines. I've edited the original question to reflect that.

Comment: Now that you edited the question, my answer is totally different. "You can't coordinate across multiple systems with `yum`. Look into `ansible` or something like that."